# How to count pair of peaks indexes including last entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, indexing

I have hit a roadblock trying to include the last entry of an index to the output. 
A pair of peaks is defined by a set of neighbouring values in a list that is higher than 3. 
How can I include the index of the last entry into the output?

```
data_series_1 = [6,4,5,2,2,0,5,4,4,2,0,2,2,1,4,2,2,5,4,6]
def paired_peaks(data_series,threshold):
    peaks =[]
    for k in range(0,len(data_series)-1):
        y_b = data_series[k-1]
        y= data_series[k]
        y_a = data_series[k+1]

        if y>threshold:
            if y_b>threshold or y_a>threshold:
                peaks.append(k)

    return peaks

print(paired_peaks(data_series_1,3))
```

I expected it to be `[0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 17, 18, 19]`, however the actual output is `[0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 17, 18]`.

Comment: Your loop exits right before it checks the last index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem happens when `for` loops comes to the end. When you get to the last element, you are trying to read the element that comes after it, and the element does not exist.

What might tricked you is because `data_series[-1]` actually read the last element instead of rising error.

Now, I don't know what your intentions are with your program, do you want to read the first element instead of nonexistant element? I assumed you do because first element is compared to the last and second one.

To fix your problem I did:

```
data_series_1 = [6,4,5,2,2,0,5,4,4,2,0,2,2,1,4,2,2,5,4,6]
def paired_peaks(data_series,threshold):
    peaks =[]
    l = len(data_series)
    for k in range(l):
        y_b = data_series[k-1]
        y= data_series[k]
        y_a = data_series[(k+1)%l]
    if y > threshold:
        if y_b > threshold or y_a > threshold:
            peaks.append(k)
    return peaks
print(paired_peaks(data_series_1,3))
```

I added wrote the length of `data_series` to variable `l` and then instead checked module value with `data_series[(k+1)%l]` to ensure your first element is read instead of nonexistant one.

This works as intended, however I advise you to check whether you want your first element to be compared to last element and do you want your last element be compared to the first element.

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your problem:

```
data_series_1 = [6,4,5,2,2,0,5,4,4,2,0,2,2,1,4,2,2,5,4,6]
def paired_peaks(data_series,threshold):
    peaks =[]
    for k in range(len(data_series)):
        y_b = data_series[k-1] if k - 1 in range(len(data_series)) else 0
        y= data_series[k]
        y_a = data_series[k+1] if k + 1 in range(len(data_series)) else 0

        if y>threshold:
            if y_b>threshold or y_a>threshold:
                peaks.append(k)

    return peaks

print(paired_peaks(data_series_1,3))

# returns: [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 17, 18, 19]
```

The reason your calculations stopped too early was because of: `range(0,len(data_series)-1)`. You exited the loop to early. I also added `if k +/- 1 in range(len(data_series)) else 0` to your code because the first item and last item of your list have no neighbour so it should be zero I assume. For the last item this would otherwise raise an Error because it's out of bounds. For the first item this didn't raise an error because `data_series_1[-1]` return the **last** item of your list, but I don't think that was intended in your code.